# what's wrong with this javacard .cap file?

Tags: applet, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I have a fresh java card and two .cap file! 
one of them successfully installed on the card (and deleted successfully!) and the another one failed to upload and install. I put the output of "GPJ" in the below. what's wrong with the .cap file? and how I can fix it?

I made cap file with Eclipse and its source code is in [this](http://umer555.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/java-card-hello-world-applet/) link.
and this is output of 'gpj'

[image]

thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload a .cap file on Smart Card?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670367/upload-a-cap-file-on-smart-card)

Comment: yes, you right. My friend asked that question with my account :) thankyou :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a wide range of possiblities for this error, as smartcard return codes are not vvery specific, my thoughts would be:

- check for correct JavaCard Version(cap file must be compiled for the version supported by your card)
- your code uses an api call that is nit supported by your card(its manufacturers decision which algorithms he supports or not)

try read Global Platform Specification for these detailed questions