# Install cap file in card with error 6985

Tags: applet, javacard

I want to install my applet on card.
I generated cap file in eclipse with java card tool menu and generate script option.
I used gpshell.exe for install my applet.
my card supports java card platform 2.2.1 but eclipse generates cap file with java card platform 2.2.2 thus I did all steps in link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307756/eclipse-generated-cap-file-cannot-be-installed-on-javacard) for recompile my applet with 2.2.1 [image]
but I'm not sure I did successful.Is another solotion to recompile my applet with jdk 2.2.1 exactly with eclipse?

I run gpshell scripts for install my applet:
step Install for load is executed successful but
load -file test.cap I get error 6985.

I will send my result[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload a .cap file on Smart Card?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670367/upload-a-cap-file-on-smart-card)

Comment: these are  not same. but I add a  comment and I want to delete this post. but I could not

Comment: These questions are pretty much exact duplicates. And the answer to that other question even suggests what you seem to have already found out: "*The most common one (assuming that the card is a Java Card) is that the applet is compiled for a different Java Card API than the card supports.*"

Comment: No these are not same. becuase I checked .my card supports java card platform 2.2.1 but eclipse generates cap file with java card platform 2.2.2 thus I did all steps in question link  . I can send you my result capture in gpshell and gp.exe. can you help me?

Comment: Correct. Your question is no longer an exact duplicate (still close though) since [your edit(!) on 2016-08-25 09:23:00Z](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39110316/5), more than 19 hours after I postd my comment (on 2016-08-24 14:08:58Z) and more than 27 hours after I flagged the question (on 2016-08-24  06:02:15Z).

Comment: So to answer your question: You need to compile your applet with the JCDK matching the Java Card version of your CAP file.

Comment: Thank you for answer.I generate my cap file with eclipse that is use java development kit 2.2.2 but my card supports java card platform 2.2.1. I donot know how to recompile my applet with eclipse and  java card platform 2.2.1. I did steps in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307756/eclipse-generated-cap-file-cannot-be-installed-on-javacard"  I think ,my cap is generated successful. I attached eclipse result. but  my problem not solved and I have error 6985.

Comment: card seller saied me .java card version is 2.2.1. Can I check it myself? may be seller made a mistacke :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can not use eclipse to generat cap file with version 2.2.1 but I can do it with JCISDE (java Cos)